# How to avoid thread blockage during concurrent sorting with a java.text.Collator?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

I have a problem with threads blocking in `java.text.RuleBasedCollator.getCollationKey()` when my server is under heavy load.

Here is the class in which the problem occurs:

```
public class DefaultFacetDisplayNameComparator implements Comparator
{
    private final Collator trTRCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("tr", "TR"));

    @Override
    public int compare(final FacetValue value1, final FacetValue value2)
    {
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value1.getDisplayName()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(value2.getDisplayName()))
        {
            //KOTT-672
            final CollationKey displayName1 = trTRCollator.getCollationKey(value1.getDisplayName());
            final CollationKey displayName2 = trTRCollator.getCollationKey(value2.getDisplayName());
            return displayName1.compareTo(displayName2);
        }
        else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(value1.getName()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(value2.getName()))
        {
            //KOTT-672
            final CollationKey name1 = trTRCollator.getCollationKey(value1.getName());
            final CollationKey name2 = trTRCollator.getCollationKey(value2.getName());
            return name1.compareTo(name2);
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Here is a snippet from a thread dump, showing the problematic blockage:

> "xxxHTTP227" prio=5 tid=0x355 nid=0x163 BLOCKED     owned by
>   hybrisHTTP109 Id=236 - stats: cpu=339 blk=-1 wait=-1 
>   java.lang.Thread.State: BLOCKED   at
>   java.text.RuleBasedCollator.getCollationKey(RuleBasedCollator.java:597)
>     - waiting to lock java.text.RuleBasedCollator@1b9f75ac  at com.core.commercesearch.search.solrfacetsearch.comparators.DefaultFacetDisplayNameComparator.compare(DefaultFacetDisplayNameComparator.java:27)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.comparators.FacetDisplayNameComparator.compare(FacetDisplayNameComparator.java:1)
>     at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:265)   at
>   java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:190)  at
>   java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)  at
>   java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)    at
>   java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)  at
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.sortFacetValues(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:444)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.convertResponse(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:268)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.queryInternal(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:194)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.solrfacetsearch.search.impl.DefaultFacetSearchService.search(DefaultFacetSearchService.java:125)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.solrfacetsearch.populators.SolrSearchRequestResponsePopulator.populate(SolrSearchRequestResponsePopulator.java:68)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.solrfacetsearch.populators.SolrSearchRequestResponsePopulator.populate(SolrSearchRequestResponsePopulator.java:1)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.converters.impl.AbstractPopulatingConverter.populate(AbstractPopulatingConverter.java:61)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.converter.impl.AbstractPopulatingConverter.convert(AbstractPopulatingConverter.java:40)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchService.doSearch(DefaultSolrProductSearchService.java:127)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchService.searchAgain(DefaultSolrProductSearchService.java:111)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchService.searchAgain(DefaultSolrProductSearchService.java:1)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade$4.execute(DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade.java:184)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade$4.execute(DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade.java:1)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.threadcontext.impl.DefaultThreadContextService.executeInContext(DefaultThreadContextService.java:54)
>     at
>   de.hybris.platform.commercefacades.search.solrfacetsearch.impl.DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade.categorySearch(DefaultSolrProductSearchFacade.java:177)
>     at
>   com.acme.storefront.controllers.pages.CategoryPageController$CategorySearchEvaluator.doSearch(CategoryPageController.java:918)

How can I avoid my server threads blocking as the thread dump shows them doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not have guessed that any `Collator`'s `getCollationKey()` implementation would need to synchronize, but that's what the thread dump seems to be showing.  It's unclear from the question, but I'm inclined to think that although this might *slow* your application when multiple threads share a `Collator`, it would not deadlock them.

Either way, however, the best solution is probably for each thread to use its own `Collator` instance, and the best way of doing that would probably be for each thread to have its own instance of the host class, `DefaultFacetDisplayNameComparator`.

That does suppose that `Collator.getInstance()` will return a different `Collator` instance each time it is invoked.  If you find that it returns the same instance on different invocations by different threads, and that that instance has a synchronization problem, then first, file a bug report; and second, use a different technique to obtain your `Collator`s (maybe building appropriate `RuleBasedCollator`s directly).

Answer (score 0):

When i got rid of Collator class usage in my case such as below, seems that i could prevent to blocked threads so it works like a charm!

```
private static final String TRtr_ALPHABET = "0123456789AaBbCcÇçDdEeFfGgĞğHhIıİiJjKkLlMmNnOoÖöPpQqRrSsŞşTtUuÜüVvWwXxYyZz";

@Override
public int compare(final FacetValue facetValue1, final FacetValue facetValue2)
{
    String value1 = null;
    String value2 = null;

    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(facetValue1.getDisplayName()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(facetValue2.getDisplayName()))
    {
        value1 = facetValue1.getDisplayName();
        value2 = facetValue2.getDisplayName();
    }
    else if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(facetValue1.getName()) && !StringUtils.isEmpty(facetValue2.getName()))
    {
        value1 = facetValue1.getName();
        value2 = facetValue2.getName();
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }

    final int length = Math.min(value1.length(), value2.length());
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < length) && (value1.charAt(i) == value2.charAt(i)))
    {
        i++;
    }
    if (i == length)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    if (TRtr_ALPHABET.indexOf(value1.charAt(i)) < TRtr_ALPHABET.indexOf(value2.charAt(i)))
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 1;
}
```